# Variable in all classes but only has value during runtime

Tags: java

Assuming I have 4 JAVA classes all with variable A. This variable A only has value depending on the value inputted by the user during runtime.

Example:

Class Abc

```
int a;
int sum = 0;
sum = a + 5;
```

Class Bcd

```
int a;
int sum = 0;
sum = a + 4;
```

Class Cde

```
int a;
int sum = 0;
sum = a + 3;
```

Class Def

```
int a;
int sum = 0;
sum = a + 2;
```

During runtime, there is a field that asks the user for value A and when user inputs value such as 10, all variable 'a's in all classes will have the value 10.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Hi, thanks. How can I do that? I cannot use getters and setters for this requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Jordi Castilla  is your friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if:

- you create constructors assigning `a`

  ```
  class Abc {

      int a;  
      int sum;

      // specific constructor receiving a
      Abc(int a) {
         this.a = a;
         this.sum = a + 5;
      }
  }
  ```
- you create classes instances after ask for user's input:

  ```
  // ask user's input
  int userInput = // ask for number.
  Abc abc = new Abc(userInput);
  abc.sum  // here you have the value
  ```

ADD-ON: instead of calculing sum at the constructor you can create a method like:

```
class Abc {

    int a;  

    // specific constructor receiving a
    Abc(int a) {
       this.a = a;
       this.sum = a + 5;
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return this.a + 5;
    }

}
```

And in main:

```
// ask user's input
int userInput = // ask for number.
Abc abc = new Abc(userInput);
int sum = abc.getSum();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I'm looking for thanks. :)